# What is the antonym to tech-savvy?

Tags: single-word-requests, acronyms

I think I can use tech-illiterate. However, this word seems to have a negative aura. Is there any word choice with a more positive feel?

Comment: I think you mean antonym, not acronym.

Comment: Could you possibly explain why you need to know this?  It is not listed in the (US) Merriam Webster dictionary online but is in the (British) Cambridge dictionary.  No antonym is offered.  You ask for "the" antonym, as of there is already an established word.  That doesn't seem to be so.  Your question needs to explain what you are trying to say.  the word "savvy" has a positive flavour, so you would expect its antonym to be negative.

Comment: I'd use *naïve*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luddite (n.)
also luddite, 1811, the name taken by an organized band of weavers in Midlands and northern England who for about 5 years thereafter destroyed machinery, for fear it would deprive them of work. Supposedly they got it from Ned Ludd, a Leicestershire worker who in 1779 had smashed two machines in a rage, but that story first was told in 1847. Applied by 1961 to modern spurners of automation and technology. As an adjective from 1812.